# How to achieve multiple inheritance in java

Tags: java

I am designing Traveller App. For which I need to design 'Traveller' class and with its instance I should be able to access properties of different types of Travel modes.

```
class Traveller {

// common properties.
}

class RoadTravel {
 // properties specific to class
}

class WaterTravel {
// properties specific to class
}

class RailTravel {
// properties specific to class
}
```

from the above code , I just want to create instance of 'Traveller' class and should be able to access the properties of all other classes (RoadTravel,WaterTravel,RailTravel).

I dont want to create any dependency on my sub classes and also my instance variables should not be final.

Please suggest good way of implementation so that it should be easy to add any new type of Travel mode in future.

Comment: Just extends `RoadTravel` and the other classes to `Traveller`. When you will declare new subtype classes you will be able to access the common attribute. You cannot make the opposite to make it work with future implementation avoid changing code.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you cannot have a class which extends (inherits) from multiple classes. (You might want to look into the *Deadly Diamond of Death* Problem.

In your case, what you could have would be a `Travel` interface which defines the behaviour each of your travel types need to expose, such as `cost(int duration)`, `getName()`. etc/

Your logic would then use the `Travel` interface to do it's logic. The travel type dependent logic would be stored in the seperate classes which make use of the `Travel` interface. Your main logic would then delegate travel specific logic to these classes which are passed to it at run time.

You will need to take a look at the [`Strategy Design Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to see how you can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

A way to implement multiple inheritance in java is the use of proxies.
Your requirements do not seem very clear and so I cannot suggest a complete solution.

If you provide an example of client code that will use these classes, I can suggest in more details how to implement it using proxies.